# php/jquery mail form, how to get a value of how many times a specific charcter there is in a text field

Tags: php, jquery

i'm trying to make this work. I have a text field "Workers name" and in this field a user should enter multiple workers name eg, Jhon, Patrick, etc and then i need a second text field that will show how many times the , appers or how many blank spaces there is so that the user can see how many workes names they have entered. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can not count by comma or spaces... what about the last name? instead split it up based on commas and spaces and then get the length.

```
//get the string into a variable with jquery
inputString = 'steve, dan, june, ward, beaver';

//match the characters and count them
wordCount = inputString.split(/[ ,]+/).length;

alert (commaCount);//shows 5
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/65xL2f8e/

Comment: Yes, but i dont know what the inputString will be.